# Check constraint for mutually exclusive columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

If I have a SQLAlchemy declarative model like below:

```
class Test(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...
    Atest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Atests.id'), nullable=True)
    Btest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Btests.id'), nullable=True)
    Ctest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Ctests.id'), nullable=True)
    Dtest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Dtests.id'), nullable=True)
    Etest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Etests.id'), nullable=True)
    ...
    date = Column(DateTime)
    status = Column(String(20))  # pass, fail, needs_review
```

And I would like to ensure that only one of the `*test_id` foreign keys is present in a given row, how might I accomplish that in `SQLAlchemy`?

I see that there is an `SQLAlchemy` `CheckConstraint` object [(see docs)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint), but `MySQL` does not support check constraints.

The data model has interaction outside of `SQLAlchemy`, so preferably it would be a database-level check (`MySQL`)

Comment: *Note that some databases do not actively support check constraints such as MySQL.*

Comment: For mysql, see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html,
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/two-nullable-columns-one-required-to-have-value

Comment: @7stud updated question to reflect that.

Comment: @7stud the second link looks like it would be applicable, although I am wondering if there is a way to build that logic to elegantly handle `n` columns for the check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, considering your requisites *"The data model has interaction outside of SQLAlchemy, so preferably it would be a database-level check (MySQL)"* and *'ensure that only one [..] is not null'*. I think the best approach is to write a trigger like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_null_insert BEFORE INSERT 
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT_WS('', NEW.a-NEW.a, NEW.b-NEW.b, NEW.c-NEW.c)) = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE `Error: Only one value of *test_id must be not null` SET z=0;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Some tricks and considerations:

1. **IF STATEMENT**: In order to avoid the tedious writing of check each column is not null while others are null, I did this trick: Reduce each column to one character and check how many characters exist. Note that `NEW.a-NEW.a` always returns 1 character if `NEW.a` is an `Integer`, `NULL` returns 0 characters and the operation `NULL-NULL` returns `NULL` on MySQL.
2. **ERROR TRIGGERING**: I suppose you want to raise an error, so how to do this on MySQL? You didn't mention the MySQL version. Only [on MySQL 5.5 you can use the SIGNAL syntax to throw an exception](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html). So the more portable way is issuing an invalid statement like: `UPDATE xx SET z=0`. If you are using MySQL 5.5 you could use: `signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Error: Only one value of *test_id must be not null';` instead of `` UPDATE `Error: Only one value of *test_id must be not null` SET z=0; ``

Also, I think you want to check this on updates too, so use:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_null_update BEFORE UPDATE 
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT_WS('', NEW.a-NEW.a, NEW.b-NEW.b, NEW.c-NEW.c)) = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE `Error: Only one value of *test_id must be not null` SET z=0;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Or create a stored procedure and call it.

### Update

For databases that supports *check constraints*, the code is more simple, see **this example for SQL Server**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (col1 INT NULL, col2 INT NULL, col3 INT NULL);
GO

ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckOnlyOneColumnIsNull
CHECK (
  LEN(CONCAT(col1-col1, col2-col2, col3-col3)) = 1
)
GO
```